# What happens if I power arduino with an external power of 12V/2A

Tags: arduino, power-supply, servo

I am connecting a device which needs 5V/150mA and a micro sg90 servo.
Would it be ok if i connected them via external adapter of 12V/2A.Normally if i connect them with a USB, my servo is giving jitter.

Comment: can you draw how you intend to connect the same. words some time do not lead to correct understanding.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your code/connections rather than the power supply

Answer (score 0):

For the case of Arduino, it is okay, because it has a voltage regulator included, which steps down voltage to 5 and 3.3 Volts. So for 12 Volts, you should be fine, just connect a 12V DC Adapter to the power jack.

Comment: He mentioned that his arduino project consumes around 500mA. If you use 12V power source, regulator would have to drop 7V at 500mA, which gives 3.5W power dissipation. Are you sure Arduino's regulator is capable of this?

Comment: @Chupacabras I think he meant the short circuit protection fuse rating on Arduino. If powered through USB, the fuse breaks if 500 mA is exceeded

Answer (score -2):

No, it's not okay.

If you connect 12V power to a 5V device (such as your Arduino, or your servo, or the other device you didn't specify) you will almost certainly destroy the device. Don't do that.

Maybe you could find a 5V adapter, such as a USB charger (which often go up to 2A or slightly more).

Comment: But the output of arduino is around 500 mA when powered thru a USB

Comment: @ManojKSharma Power all three devices directly from the USB charger then